# read NetCDF into R as a raster stack

Tags: r, raster, netcdf

I have 2 NetCDF files that cover the measurement of the same variable (hurs) for two different time periods (1:2035-2054, 2:2055-2074). I want to read these into R as a raster stack and extract the time period 2041-2070 All files have the following time unit : parent_time_units: days since 1850-1-1 00:00:00. The data is in monthly resolution.
How is this done?

I have tried a loop, to combine the two files in a raster stack. But then i am not sure how to extract the time period.
Thats what i did so far:

```
library(raster)

# List of file names
file_names <- c("hurs_Amon_MPI-ESM1-2-LR_ssp126_r10i1p1f1_gn_203501-205412.nc","hurs_Amon_MPI-ESM1-2-LR_ssp126_r10i1p1f1_gn_205501-207412.nc")

#Initialize the output stack
output_stack <- stack()

# Loop over the files and stack them into the output stack
for (file_name in file_names) {
  data <- raster(file_name)
  output_stack <- stack(output_stack, data)
}

# Print the output stack
print(output_stack)
```

This ends in the following result:

```
> # Print the output stack
> print(output_stack)
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 96, 192, 18432, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 1.875, 1.864677  (x, y)
extent     : -0.9375, 359.0625, -89.50451, 89.50451  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : Near.Surface.Relative.Humidity.1, Near.Surface.Relative.Humidity.2
```

Now I am stuck extracting the desired time period.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? We need to know what libraries you are using etc

Comment: @RobertWilson i have added my code above

Comment: You've changed the question a reasonable amount. Can you re-read and ensure all details are actually in it? Your original question did not specify that you wanted to extract 2041-2070. If you want to extract those years why are you reading in 2015-2034 and 2075 onwards? It's still hard to figure out what you are trying to do

Comment: @RobertWilson That's right, the code before was a bit confusing. I have now adapted the code accordingly to what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terra` R package in place of `raster` which is much faster like

```
library(terra)

#Create a list of .nc files
files <- list.files(path = getwd(), #In place of `getwd()`, you can provide the directory containing .nc files
                    pattern = "\\.nc$", full.names = TRUE)

# stack rasters
output_stack <- rast(files)
```